# SQL Server Report Builder from Citrix

Tags: sql-server, citrix, ssrs

We would like to allow users accessing the system via citrix to create their own reports using SQL Server Report Builder.

Has anyone tried this? Did it work or were there any problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have managed to get this to work quite easily and in fact it's the only way we provide access to Report Builder.

- Citrix XenApp 4.5
- Windows Server 2003 (enterprise)
- MS SQL Server 2005

Different versions may have different nuances!

Make sure you run Report Builder on the Citrix XenApp server as an account with Administrator privileges in order to authorise the Report Builder ActiveX control.